# String sets its Value to "False"

Tags: vb.net, string

So, I'm currently working on a program that should create Lua-Scripts for the Unitale-Engine. I added a "New Project" button which should create a new project file when you click it. I want this file to contain the default project-file-text. So i did this:

```
Dim File1 As String = "monster{" & vbNewLine & "COMMENTS=Ribbit, ribbit.;Croak, croak.;Hop, hop.;Meow." & vbNewLine & "COMMANDS=Compliment;Threaten" & vbNewLine & "DEFAULT_SPRITE=None" & vbNewLine & "NAME=Froggit" & vbNewLine & "HP=10" & vbNewLine & "ATK=1" & vbNewLine = "DEF=0" & vbNewLine & "CHECK_MESSAGE=Life is difficult for this enemy." & vbNewLine & "HandleAttack=" & vbNewLine & "OnDeath=" & vbNewLine & "HandleCustomCommand=" & vbNewLine & "}"
Dim File2 As String = vbNewLine & "encounter{" & vbNewLine & "DEFAULT_MUSIC=Fight" & vbNewLine & "ENCOUNTER_TEXT=Froggit hops close." & vbNewLine & "NEXTWAVES=1" & vbNewLine & "WAVETIMER=6" & vbNewLine & "ARENASIZE=155;130" & vbNewLine & "ENEMIES=Froggit" & vbNewLine & "ENEMYPOSITIONS=0;0" & "EncounterStarting=" & vbNewLine & "EnemyDialogueStarting=" & vbNewLine & "EnemyDialogueEnding=" & vbNewLine & "DefenseEnding=" & vbNewLine & "HandleItem=" & vbNewLine & "HandleSpare=" & vbNewLine & "EnteringState=" & vbNewLine & "Update=" & vbNewLine & "}"
Dim File3 As String = vbNewLine & "waves{" & vbNewLine & "1=Do Nothing" & vbNewLine & "}" & vbNewLine & "end"
My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments & "\UnitaleMaker\Projects\" & PJNBox.Text & ".umproj", File1 & File2 & File3, False)
```

Yes, that is a lot of text. The problem is, that `File1` always sets its value to `"False"` when it is declared. I thought that is because the string is too long, so I split it to 3 parts, but it doesn't work.

Any help would be apprechiated!

~ Mika // OneByte_

Comment: You have `=` in the middle (`... & vbNewLine = "DEF=0" & ...`).

Comment: How did I not notice that!? I looked through it multiple times... Whatever, thank you! That was the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with [VB 14 (Visual Studio 2015)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn890368.aspx), you can span String literals across multiple lines. VB 14 also adds String interpolation, which makes for much cleaner code. You could write your code like the following which would have kept you from having made your mistake of `& vbNewLine = "DEF=0" &`and would overall make the code easier to read.

I am also assuming you forgot a newline in `"ENEMYPOSITIONS=0;0" & "EncounterStarting="` and I have indented the parts between the `{}`. I combined `File1`, `File2`, and `File3` back into a single string since you stated you broke them up in the question, I assumed you'd rather have it all in one string.

```
Dim File1 As String = "monster{
    COMMENTS = Ribbit, ribbit.;Croak, croak.;Hop, hop.;Meow.
    COMMANDS=Compliment;Threaten
    DEFAULT_SPRITE=None
    NAME=Froggit
    HP=10
    ATK=1
    DEF=0
    CHECK_MESSAGE=Life Is difficult For this enemy.
    HandleAttack=
    OnDeath=
    HandleCustomCommand=
}
encounter{
    DEFAULT_MUSIC = Fight
    ENCOUNTER_TEXT =Froggit hops close.
    NEXTWAVES=1
    WAVETIMER=6
    ARENASIZE=155;130
    ENEMIES=Froggit
    ENEMYPOSITIONS=0;0
    EncounterStarting=
    EnemyDialogueStarting=
    EnemyDialogueEnding=
    DefenseEnding=
    HandleItem=
    HandleSpare=
    EnteringState=
    Update=
}
waves{
    1 =Do Nothing
}
End"
My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText($"{My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments}\UnitaleMaker\Projects\{PJNBox.Text}.umproj", File1, False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please learn to use [string.format](http://www.dotnetperls.com/format-vbnet).

Also I changed `&` to `new line` in `file2`:

```
"ENEMYPOSITIONS=0;0" & "EncounterStarting="
```

I just assumed you forgot to add new line there.

Alss `Environment.NewLine` is the best option for new lines as it is universal.

```
Dim File1 As String = String.Format("monster{{{0}COMMENTS=Ribbit, ribbit.;Croak, croak.;Hop, hop.;Meow.{0}COMMANDS=Compliment;Threaten{0}DEFAULT_SPRITE=None{0}NAME=Froggit{0}HP=10{0}ATK=1{0}DEF=0{0}CHECK_MESSAGE=Life is difficult for this enemy.{0}HandleAttack={0}OnDeath={0}HandleCustomCommand={0}}}", Environment.NewLine)
    Dim File2 As String = String.Format("{0}encounter{{{0}DEFAULT_MUSIC=Fight{0}ENCOUNTER_TEXT=Froggit hops close.{0}NEXTWAVES=1{0}WAVETIMER=6{0}ARENASIZE=155;130{0}ENEMIES=Froggit{0}ENEMYPOSITIONS=0;0{0}EncounterStarting={0}EnemyDialogueStarting={0}EnemyDialogueEnding={0}DefenseEnding={0}HandleItem={0}HandleSpare={0}EnteringState={0}Update={0}}}", Environment.NewLine)
    Dim File3 As String =  String.Format("{0}waves{{{0}1=Do Nothing{0}}}{0}end", Environment.NewLine)
    My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments & "\UnitaleMaker\Projects\" & PJNBox.Text & ".umproj", File1 & File2 & File3, False)
```

Comment: It is arguable that mass-inserting new lines is better done with `string.format`. These are string literals known at compile time, and compiler can merge them all into a single string that won't require processing afterwards. It is certainly arguable that `Environment.NewLine` should be used, because `Environment.NewLine` can have different values depending on the environment, whereas `vbNewLine` always equals `\r\n`, and it is better to use a fixed separator when persisting data to file.

Comment: As you said `Environment.NewLine` have different values at different environments but always means new line. That's the point of it. The reason for using `string.format` is to have more readable code because it saves space and you don't have to connect strings using `&` which is prone to mistakes proved by op question.

Comment: You save the file when `Environment.NewLine` equals `\r`. You read that file back when `Environment.NewLine` equals `\n`. Boom. String.format is also not an example of readability in this particular case because of all the `{` you had to escape, that is also error prone.